# Who is the correct owner and group for these system files? (Digital Ocean Droplet running Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: ubuntu-20.04, digital-ocean

This should be a simple answer for anyone using a Digital Ocean droplet on Ubuntu 20.04. I accidentally ran a command that changed ownership and group of a bunch of files in `/var` (outside the directory I was working in). I've managed to restore the owner/group on most of the files, but I am not sure what the owner/group for the following files should be:

```
/var/log/droplet-agent.update.log
/var/log/ubuntu-advantage-timer.log
/var/log/ubuntu-advantage.log
```

If anybody has a Digital Ocean droplet with these files, will you please post the owner/group info? It could be root:root or it could be root:syslog or it could be anything else for that matter.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After creating another droplet, I was able to check, and all of these files should be owned by `root:root`.